# Поскажите как с помощью Zabbix мониторить интернет трафик

Tags: linux, bash, devops, zabbix, мониторинг

На данной момент на VM1 установлен zabbix сервер, а на VM2 zabbix агент. Так же на VM2  установил speedtest (скачивал отсюда: https://www.speedtest.net/ru/apps/cli).

Задача:
Необходимо чтобы с помощью UserParameters:

1. VM2 раз в 30 минут забиралась скорость скачивания и отдачи интернет трафика и передавалась на систему мониторинга VM1
2. VM2 передавала информацию на VM1 о скорости трафика между ними.

Насколько я понимаю теперь в speedtest нужно создать пустой файл в который будут записываться данные о скорости интернета, а в nano нужно написать скрипт который собирает показатели каждые 30 мин.

Никак не пойму как осуществить данную задачу, прошу подскажите как это реализовать ? Пробовал гуглить видел различные решения либо куски решений, но мне непонятны они.

P.S. По возможности прошу разъяснить как это нужно сделать подробно.

Comment: Ну с наскока я тут вижу несколько задач. Написание скрипта, вызов по таймеру, передача инфы на заббикс сервер. Что именно у тебя не получается и что ты уже попробовал?

Comment: @donRumata, скрипт у человека вроде как есть, вызов по таймеру ЕМНИП забикс сам обеспечивает... так что ИМХО очевидно, что проблема в том, как и где погладить забикс...

Comment: На данный момент вопрос следующего характера. Сделал все как по инструкции [ссылка] (https://osbsd.com/speedtest-template-for-monitoring-in-zabbix.html), не могу теперь понять как найти в веб-интерфейсе zabbix настроенный speedtest ?